# How to smoothly slide three div in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, smooth-scrolling

I want to slide three div in a row! The effect must be smooth. There will have two button for slide with id (`#left` & `#right`. When I click the `#left` button div must slide to left and the same for `#right`. After sliding the last of three div it will start from 1st div like carousel.

Comment: Are you saying you want a carousel with 3 divs, no auto sliding, left/right buttons for manual sliding, and around the world sliding behavior (3 + forward -> 1 and 1 + backward -> 3)?

Comment: Yes. You are right!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.